# Declared double does not output what is assigned to it in C programming

Tags: c, if-statement, declaration

So once again I am learning a new programming language this time it is C.
And after creating this function for my main menu it seems like the declared double "equiv", short for equivalent, does not correctly output the assigned equivalent to it. I commented the part where it's getting the bug.

Here's the code for the function:

```
    // function for grading system
void gradeSys()
{
    char response;
    // declaration for computing midterm grades
    double Mquiz1 = 0, Mquiz2 = 0, Mquiz3 = 0, Mrecit = 0, Massign = 0, MAve = 0, Midex = 0;

    // declaration for computing final grades
    double Fquiz1 = 0, Fquiz2 = 0, Fquiz3 = 0, Frecit = 0, Fassign = 0, FAve = 0, Finex = 0;

    char answer;
    int counter = 1;
    // while loop
    while(counter != 0) {

    /*!!!---Midterm Grades Input---!!!*/
    printf("Welcome to your Grading System.\n");
    printf("Please enter your grades for Midterm:\n");
    printf("M. Quiz1:\n");
    scanf("%d" , &Mquiz1);
    printf("M. Quiz2:\n");
    scanf("%d" , &Mquiz2);
    printf("M. Quiz3:\n");
    scanf("%d" , &Mquiz3);
    printf("M. Recitation\n");
    scanf("%d" , &Mrecit);
    printf("M. Assignment\n");
    scanf("%d" , &Massign);
    printf("M. Exam:\n");
    scanf("%d" , &Midex);
    // formula for computing midterm grades
    double Midgrade = 0;
    MAve = (Mquiz1 + Mquiz2 + Mquiz3 + Mrecit + Massign)/5;
    double MAveTotal = MAve * .60;
    double MidExAve = Midex * .40;
    Midgrade = MAveTotal + MidExAve;

    printf("Your Midterm average is: %d\n", MAve);
    printf("Your Midterm Grade is: %d\n", Midgrade);
    printf("Please press enter to continue...\n");
    getchar();
    getchar();
    system("cls");

    /*!!!---Final Grades Input---!!!*/
    printf("Please enter your grades for Finals:\n");
    printf("F. Quiz1:\n");
    scanf("%d" , &Fquiz1);
    printf("F. Quiz2:\n");
    scanf("%d" , &Fquiz2);
    printf("F. Quiz3:\n");
    scanf("%d" , &Fquiz3);
    printf("F. Recitation\n");
    scanf("%d" , &Frecit);
    printf("F. Assignment\n");
    scanf("%d" , &Fassign);
    printf("F. Exam:\n");
    scanf("%d" , &Finex);
    // formula for computing final grades
    double Fingrade = 0;
    FAve = (Fquiz1 + Fquiz2 + Fquiz3 + Frecit + Fassign)/5;
    double FAveTotal = FAve * .60;
    double FinExAve = Finex * .40;
    Fingrade = FAveTotal + FinExAve;

    printf("Your Final average is: %d\n", FAve);
    printf("Your Final Grade is: %d\n", Fingrade);
    printf("Please press enter to continue...\n");
    getchar();
    getchar();
    /*!!!--- Here is where the bug occurs ---!!!*/
    // declaration and formula for the term grade
    double termGrade = 0, equiv;
    termGrade = (Midgrade + Fingrade)/2;
    // decision formula for determining equivalent
    if(termGrade >= 90 && termGrade <= 100)
    {
         equiv = 4.0;
    }
    else if(termGrade >= 85 && termGrade <= 89)
    {
         equiv = 3.0;
    }
    else if(termGrade >= 75 && termGrade <= 84)
    {
         equiv = 2.0;
    }
    else if(termGrade >= 70 && termGrade <= 74)
    {
         equiv = 1.0;
    }
    else if(termGrade >= 00 && termGrade <= 69)
    {
         equiv = 0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid grade. Try again.\n");
    }
    // displays the ovarall grade for the term and the equivalent
    printf("Your grade for this term is: %d. Which is equivalent to a: %d.\n", termGrade, equiv);
    getchar();
    system("cls");

    // try again?
        printf("Do you want to try again:[Y/N]\n");
        scanf("%c", &answer);

        if(answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')
        {
           system("cls");
           continue;            
        }
        else if(answer == 'n' || answer == 'N')
        {
           system("cls");
           counter = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid input\n");
        }

     }

}
```

Comment: You can't `printf` a double using `%d`.

Comment: Thanks! Changed it to %f like Michael said but now it doesn't choose from my if statements what value to assign to "equiv".

Comment: Same goes for `scanf`... you can't read a double using `%d`, either. Learn how to use a debugger, step over your program line by line, it'll be faster than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%d` format is intended for signed integers. For floating point numbers (e.g. a `double`) you should be using `%f`. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Alternatively you could cast the values to integers (e.g.  `(int)FAve`) and use `%d`, if you want to print just the whole part of the values.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! Changed it to %f like you said and it is working fine, it outputs a double now but it doesn't choose what to output in my if statement. It only outputs a bunch double type numbers (0.00000).

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't choose"? What are the values of `MidGrade` and `Fingrade`?

Comment: Ummm actually I'm not getting an error at displaying my Midgrade and Fingrade. The error is in the if else statements.
I assigned the termgrade to ba a condition where it is supposed to give a 4.0 to a 0.0 grade if the condition is met. But i think it doesn't go to the control statement and just outputs a 0.00000.

Comment: Without knowing what values you've got for `Midgrade` and `Fingrade` it's impossible to know what `equiv` to expect.

Comment: Midgrade and Fingrade have values. MidGrade is equal to MAveTotal + MidExAve and Fingrade is equal to FAveTotal + FinExAve.

"equiv" data is dependent on what termGrade will get.

Comment: Yeah, I realize that that's how it's _supposed_ to work. But you're saying that you get an `equiv` of 0, and without knowing what values you have input it's impossible to know what the expected output is supposed to be.

Comment: Hmmm.. I still don't get it. Sorry.
Yep I get an equiv of 0.0000 and I think equiv knows that termGrade does not have a value but it will have a generated value after going to the formula. Right? Haha! I'm still confused. I'll review my codes once again.
Thank you :]